# What is the path to the HTML file that has the admin panel stating "Welcome, please login here" in Magneto 2?

Tags: magento2

What is the path to the  HTML file that has the admin panel stating "Welcome, please login here" in Magneto 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the file path from which "Welcome, please login here" coming. then

**magento_directory/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml**